# Excel cells formatting behaviour

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel, and I'd like to know something that seems strange, or unnatural to me within Excel: Are cells formats supposed to behave like masks in non-Excel input boxes (...I'm a programmer!!): I mean, when you set a cell format to Currency, then you type in 25 for instance, that 25 will be "transormed" to $25.00, which is ok; but if I enter "blablabla" in that same Currency formatted cell, nothing happens and "blablabla" stays "blablabla", and there is no error message or anything to warn me that this cell's content is not Currency formatted. Is this the normal behaviour within Excel, or I've done something wrong?

Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the format of a cell to any format, and Excel will *try* to format as such.  As you noted, you can still enter text into a currency formatted cell, and there will be no error, and no formatting (how do you format words as a currency?).

If you want to force a cell to take only numbers (so a user can't input text), you can use [Data Validation](http://excel.tips.net/T002425_Limiting_Entries_to_Numeric_Values.html), and limit the input to Numeric values.

Highlight the cell you want, go to Data --> Data Validation.

Comment: As you say, Excel will TRY to format, so its normal behaviour is not a like a mask! And I'll definitly have a look at Data Validation....Thanks for the hint and the quick answer...

Comment: worth noting that sometimes `Data Validation` has limits. If you hit them, you can use VBA and `Worksheet_Change` event for more robust validation checking. That said, make sure you have exhausted `Data Validation` possibilities, because it's always best practice to use built-in Excel functionality over coding.

Comment: I agree @ScottHoltzman - if OP really needs this to be numbers, I'd say a VBA `Worksheet_Change` would be the better bet.

Comment: @BruceWayne - the `Allow > Whole Number | Decimal` options may work just fine :)